# Assign properties in an array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I've defined a class and have declared an array of objects under that same class, but get compile errors. I was wondering if there's something small I'm overlooking here.

```
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Tile {
    public int ID;
    public ImageView image;
}
```

When I define this class here, something goes awry.

```
Tile tile_array[][] = new Tile[3][3];


tile_array[1][1].image = new_image;
tile_array[1][1].ID = tile_counter;
```

Comment: Can we have more context surrounding the second code section, as well as the exact error you are getting. But assuming that code is in a legal place ( e.g. in a method ) -- similar code is not giving me a compile error, but instead a runtime exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see, There are two wrong thing you are doing.

1. You should allocate the [1][1] object.
   i.e. - `tile_array[1][1] = new Tile().`
2. you image object (of ImageView class) is still unallocated.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak -- I don't think this is a compile error. Using similar code, I cannot get it to have a compile error.

Comment: @Dre You should say that to OP :) I'm just quoting him.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak, even i dont see any compiler error, but just pointed wrong thing. Actually i should write this in my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to create a two dimentional array with a fixed size of 3 by 3.
Some remarks:

1. This is fixed size, meaning you can not change the size once you have initialized the object tile_array (if that is what you want, no issues)
2. Example of how this can be done within a method scope:

   ```
   Tile[][] tileArray = new Tile[3][3];  
   tileArray[1][0].ID = 1;
   tileArray[1][0].image = new ImageView(this);

   tileArray[1][1].ID = 2;
   tileArray[1][1].image = new ImageView(this);

   tileArray[1][2].ID = 3;
   tileArray[1][2].image = new ImageView(this);
   ```
3. I would suggest using an Arraylist, since this has more advantages than having to write so much code. Also is is felxible on the sizing.

Comment: tileArray[1][3] would be invalid and outside the array bounds. Java arrays are 0-based, so [1][0], [1][1], and [1][2].

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Arrow{
        public int ID;
        public static void main(String [] args){
                Arrow arrow[][] = new Arrow[3][3];
        }
}
```

compiles fine for me.

Comment: sorry I did not check before down voting.I tried to neutralize but my vote is locked.